# Django Model and Many-to-Many Relationships -- finding most similar objects

Tags: python, django, model

I'm running into an issue that I can't find an explanation for.

Given one object (in this case, an "Article"), I want to use another type of object (in this case, a "Category") to determine which other articles are most similar to article X, as measured by the number of categories they have in common. The relationship between Article and Category is Many-to-Many. The use case is to get a quick list of related Objects to present as links.

I know exactly how I would write the SQL by hand:

```
select 
    ac.article_id
from 
    Article_Category ac
where
    ac.category_id in 
    (
        select
            category_id
        from
            Article_Category
        where
            article_id = 1  -- get all categories for article in question
    )
    and ac.article_id <> 1
group by 
    ac.article_id
order by 
    count(ac.category_id) desc, random() limit 5
```

What I'm struggling with is how to use the Django Model aggregation to match this logic and only run one query. I'd obv. prefer to do it within the framework if possible. Does anybody have pointers on this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in running [raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) if they are not easy to express with django ORM syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I can certainly run the raw query, I just want to make sure that I'm not missing an easy way to implement it with ORM syntax. I'm fairly new to working with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django annotate query set with a count on subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850744/django-annotate-query-set-with-a-count-on-subquery)

Comment: There are certain things django ORM does not cover yet(and probably never will). That's why they provide raw queries.

Comment: Since you've found the answer - you can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and then accept your answer. This way, the question is closed and others will know what solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this in now that I've found a way within the model framework to do this.

```
related_article_list = Article.objects.filter(category=self.category.all())\
                       .exclude(id=self.id)
related_article_ids = related_article_list.values('id')\
                      .annotate(count=models.Count('id'))\
                      .order_by('-count','?')
```

In the related_article_list part, other Article objects that match on 2 or more Categories will be included separate times. Thus, when using annotation to count them the number will be > 1 and they can be ordered that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer if you really want to filter articles on all category should look like this:

```
related_article_list = Article.objects.filter(category__in=self.category.all())\
                       .exclude(id=self.id)
```